# The chromedriver is not working and getting ERROR: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:4444 in webdriverio frame work

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, webdriver-io

I am using webdriverIO Mocha frame work and i tried many solution but still getting the below error. So help me resolve this issue

```
[23:57:52]  COMMAND     POST     "/wd/hub/session" [23:57:52]  DATA                {"desiredCapabilities":{"javascriptEnabled":true,"locationContextEnabled":true,"handlesAlerts":true,"rotatable":true,"browserName":"firefox","platform":"macOS
10.12","version":"latest","build":"MAC_CHROME","pageLoadStrategy":"normal","acceptSslCerts":true,"_":"2 more keys: [\"loggingPrefs\",\"requestOrigins\"]"}} ERROR: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:4444
```

Comment: Do you have selenium webdriver and firefox node running at 127.0.0.1:4444?

Comment: **"version":"latest"** ... How?

Comment: Yes i have selenium webdriver and how to verify whether the firefox node running at 127.0.0.1:4444

Comment: selenium webdriver version - selenium-webdriver@3.6.0

Answer (score 9):

The best practice is to use "**selenium-standalone**" and "**wdio-selenium-standalone-service**" npm packages, so if you don't have them in devDependencies in your package.json, add them.

Once you have these packages, you need first to download and install selenium drivers with console command: `./node_modules/.bin/selenium-standalone install --config=./config/selenium.config.js`, where your selenium.config.js file should look like [this](https://github.com/vvo/selenium-standalone/blob/HEAD/lib/default-config.js)
.

Once installed, the "**wdio-selenium-standalone-service**" will automatically start the node server for you each time before tests start (if you use wdio testrunner)

Comment: The url provided for the selenium.config.js an example should be converted into an object. I remove the function and convert it into an object and it started installing but after trying to run dwio testrunner it still didnt work

Answer (score 1):

I also face the problem of Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:4444.
Try many ways like: update Chrome, update ChromeDriver, set environment Path, but still doesn't work. 
Then, I update my Java runtime, now it can work now.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced with this issue and I try the following and this issue is resolved.

- Check the `Java JDK` installed?

`$javac -version`

If have no installed, please install it

Answer (score 0):

I have also faced the same issue by restarting the PC and installing the below package worked for me

> npm install --save-dev @wdio/local-runner